# select a part of a sentence instead of the whole sentence with clipboard

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, clipboard, notify

I want my program instead of selecting the whole sentence for a return, that a part of sentence is also possible if a copied that.

here's my code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    //check if current operation is a clipboard
    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    {
        //then we use a try catch block so if 
        //anything wrong happens in Clipboard.GetText() our program wont crash
        try
        {
            //with foreach we go through all our questions
            foreach (string question in questionList)
            {
                //and we check if clapboarded text is matches with our question
                if (Clipboard.GetText() == "When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?")
                {
                    notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?";
                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Install a modular power supply.*";
                    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
                    return;
                }
```

this is the question: "When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?"

i want for example if you copied this: When a computer is being assembled, which

You get the same match and the same notification

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do your best to clarify what do you expect to happen in which case and what actually happens. For now, the question sounds very unclear. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use string method .Contains() instead of equality comparison.

```
if (Clipboard.GetText().Contains(yourString))
```